# Android test if it having data else return to first

Tags: android, if-statement, textview

I have android apps:

1. Send data to Textview (working)
2. check if data is there getdata from text view(working)
3. Else if data not in Textview check again ??

Thanks.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //enter text to TextView (tv1) need some time
            EntertextToTextView();

                   //label1

                if (tv1.getText().toString() != "")
                 {
                    tv2.setText(tv1.getText().toString());
                  } 
             else {

                   // goto label1;
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your question again?!

Comment: If the data is not in textview goto check again till the data is there and enter to if

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Try something on your own. Then come back and post some code, maybe. Let us know where you're stuck.

Comment: If you have added text to text view, why would it not appear in the textview as you entered it?

Comment: it is taking some time